# Wireless internet connection randomly disconnects in dell inspiron N5110

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

Wireless connection goes off randomly. I also have a windows 7 installed along with ubuntu.
I didn't install any extra drivers for it. It works sometimes.
I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I tried to add some images but i need 10 repo points to do so.. Here are the links to those images
![output of the command sudo lshw -class network](http://i.imgur.com/K9YYqhR.png) 
![output of the command rfkill list all, lsusb, lspci](http://i.imgur.com/gwBjQNE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem caused by some kernel versions. Try to upgrade, or downgrade and see if it helps.

You can download different versions from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: There are lot of files to download, can you be more specific.

Comment: here are the links to images which may give insight where is the problem. 
![output of the command sudo lshw -class network](http://i.imgur.com/K9YYqhR.png) 
![output of the command rfkill list all, lsusb, lspci](http://i.imgur.com/gwBjQNE.png)

Comment: Try this command "uname -a" and post the result for me to suggest a different kernel version. I am assuming its 3.13 more or less.

Comment: Linux apram-Inspiron-N5110 3.5.0-51-generic #77~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 5 00:48:28 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try this version and escalate: 3.12.5-031205-generic
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.5-trusty/
Download also version 3.14, 3.15 and see if they are better.

Comment: hey can you also teach how to install these....

Comment: I would've suggested that you update first, but it is hard with your wireless dropping every few seconds. Download this directly It is simple, just download this one to begin with and then reboot.
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.5-trusty/linux-headers-3.12.5-031205-generic_3.12.5-031205.201312120254_amd64.deb
This is the 64 bit. After you install that reboot, if your wireless runs fine, go ahead and install the updates by running "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: Ohk it was getting over my head so i upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, Thanks for the help bdw.